# How do I clear dataitems from select2

Tags: jquery-select2-4

I would like to refill the options of my select2, the old options should not be available only the new ones. I have a select2 that is filled with the following data:

```
$('select')
    .select2({
    data: [{
        id: 'Spock',
        text: 'Spock'
    }, {
        id: 'Kirk',
        text: 'Kirk'
    }]
})
```

Now I would like to replace the option with StarWars alternatives like this:

```
$('select')
    .select2({
    data: [{
        id: 'Luke',
        text: 'Luke'
    }, {
        id: 'Darth',
        text: 'Darth'
    }]
})
```

The result when after both scripts are run, is a select2 that contains both StarTrek and StarWars dudes. How do I remove the old items?
Here is a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/052rr9tn/) with the example above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the previous options of select box before replacing the StarWars alternatives using `$('select').html('');`. So your code would be like this:

```
$('select')
    .select2({
    data: [{
        id: 'Spock',
        text: 'Spock'
    }, {
        id: 'Kirk',
        text: 'Kirk'
    }]
});

$('select').html('');   // use this to remove previous options

$('select')
    .select2({
    data: [{
        id: 'Luke',
        text: 'Luke'
    }, {
        id: 'Darth',
        text: 'Darth'
    }]
});
```

See this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/052rr9tn/1/)** for more details.